# Type ambiguity between assembly versions

Tags: c#, .net, version, assembly-binding-redirect

I have the following line of code that generates an error:

```
public class AccountController : ApiController
```

The error is:

> CS0433    The type 'ApiController' exists in both 'System.Web.Http,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
>   and 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

I have a very novice attempt at an assembly redirect, but how hard are they anyway?

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding  xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

The redirect seems to have no effect at all.

My current choice is to eliminate one of the versions, and I'd much prefer to dump the old 4.0.0.0, but with clashes between required libraries seem to make this difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Your *oldVersion* upper limit is equal to the *newVersion*. Try *0.0.0.0-5.2.2.999*, that may help.

Comment: Those two versions being the same is extremely common in nearly all of MS's redirects.

Comment: All it means is that, even if I ask for the latest version, you redirect me to the latest version.

Comment: Hmm, the `<dependentAssembly>` XML element in your configuration file is missing, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/bindingredirect-element).

Comment: Saw this too late.